# How would I differentiate an integral with bounds?

Tags: integration, derivatives

Let $\space f \space$ be a differentiable function of $\space x \space$.

Now I know that for the following integral:

$$I=\int f(x) \space dx$$

Clearly:

$${dI\over dx}=f(x)$$

Since integration is also known as the *anti-derivative*.

But what if the integral had bounds?

For example:

$$I= \int_{a}^{b} f(x) \space dx \quad a,b \in \mathbb{R}$$

Would $\space {dI\over dx} \space$ equal $\space 0 \space$ in this case since the integral returns no variable $\space x$ ?

Comment: It equals zero since it's a constant for fixed $a,b$.

Comment: @CameronWilliams - Ahh I thought so. Thank you :)

Comment: "returns no variable $x$" you mean that $I$ doesn't depend on $x$

Comment: @user1952009 - Yeah that's what I meant :)